# Ionic hiding popup button from login

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark bar-custom">
    <ion-nav-back-button side="right"></ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right" ng-if ="!$state.current.name==='Emaillogin'">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-more-vertical" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

</ion-nav-bar>
```

Actually, I have placed popup button in my index.html page so that it must come up everywhere but I want to remove it from my login and signup page
i have checked it in button using ng-if but nothing happens

[image]

How to remove popup from both signup and login page !

Comment: create fiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-if statement

> ng-if !="$state.current.name==='Emaillogin'"

is wrong. it should be like

> ng-if="!($state.current.name==='Emaillogin')"  or  ng-if="$state.current.name!='Emaillogin'"

Comment: nothing works !! getting some sort of outerhtml error when using your code!! while doing this it got hide from everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong here:

1. $state can not be used in html page, use $state.current.name in Controller.
2. Your if condition is not correct.

So your code should be like:

In controller:

```
$currentState = $state.current.name
```

and in html page:

```
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right" ng-if ="currentState!='Emaillogin'">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-more-vertical" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: not working !!! i am thinking to add a dynamic template and use that in all the states by saying .state name in my config file ...just as we define fro menu a seprate file and use that file as a parent and use .state in every state config.?

Comment: its just about nested state